# Input radius for diameter, surface and circumference output is not giving me the output

Tags: java

I'm a beginner with java and have a problem. I have an assignment to do with the `java.util.scanner` class where you can put a value for `radius` in the `console` and get as output the **diameter, surface** etc.

My problem is, that I can enter the radius value, but it's not giving me the desired value for the diameter etc, only the text.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab1_Aufg1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Radius: ");
        double Radius = s.nextDouble();

        double durchmesser;
        double umfang;
        double flaeche;

        durchmesser = Radius * 2;
        umfang = 2 * Math.PI * Radius;
        flaeche = Math.PI * Radius*Radius;

        System.out.println("Durchmesser = "  durchmesser);
        System.out.println("Umfang = "  umfang);
        System.out.println("Fläche = "  flaeche);
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `s.Next();`? It won't even compile.

Comment: And also `System.out.println("Umfang = "  umfang);` is not even valid without the `+`

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: What is the expected output and what you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `Next()` to `nextDouble()` to get an double-type input.

Also, `String` objects can be appended using the `+` operator in Java. You need to fix how you append strings within your `System.out.println()` statements:

```java
System.out.println("Durchmesser = " +  durchmesser); // Need to add the '+' symbol
System.out.println("Umfang = " + umfang);
System.out.println("Fläche = " + flaeche);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I changed it, but it's still the same result

Comment: it's still not working for me... i dont know why

Comment: @nilezguyDid you change all your `System.out.println()` functions to append the strings with the `+` sign? Because the code  works properly when I run it.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I edited my Code in the Thread. This is still not working.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, you are missing a closing curly brace in the code you've posted

Comment: I'm not getting any error. There's just no value for diameter(durchmesser), umfang and flaeche. It's in the console like this: Durchmesser = 
Umfang = 
Fläche =

Comment: The code works on my end. Im getting `Durchmesser = 6.0
Umfang = 18.84955592153876
Fläche = 28.274333882308138` when I input `3` for the `radius`

Comment: is this a software problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191541/discussion-between-a-busy-programmer-and-nilezguy).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `s.Next()` to `s.nextDouble()` to get a double input. also, you need to put a `+` between the variables and the strings instead of putting a space:

`System.out.println("Durchmesser = " +  durchmesser);`

Comment: unfortunately it's still not working

Answer (score 2):

All problem fixed use this code, it'll work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class stackCircle 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Radius: ");
        double Radius = s.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("Durchmesser = %.2f\n" , Radius * 2);
        System.out.printf("Umfang = %.2f\n"  , 2 * Math.PI * Radius);
        System.out.printf("Fläche = %.2f\n" , Math.PI * (Radius*Radius)); 
        s.close();
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have added `%.2f`, this will make your output to display results up to `2 decimal positions`. This is easy to read then using `default` `8 decimal places`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `}` at the bottom of your file.

Always make sure to count your curly braces.

**Edit:**
Your code was edited by another user, if you pop it into [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler) you should see that it works now.